# Is there a different MPI command for sending Classes in C++ instead of MPI_Type_create_struct?

Tags: c++, types, mpi, message-passing

I am trying to create a parallel program using MPI which in it's serial version contains a Class like this.

```
class car {

public:
    //constructor
    car(int x, int y, int value){
        xPosition = x;
        yPosition = y;      
    }

    //deconstructor
    ~car() {
        cout << "Car deconstructor!" << endl;
    }

private:
    int xPosition;
    int yPosition;
    int ageInSteps;
    int last50Stepsx[stepHistory];
    int last50Stepsy[stepHistory];
};
```

I want to send this Class from one process to another so I think the way to do is by creating a Datatype that encloses this structure.

I see people in general use **MPI_Type_create_struct** and then **MPI_Type_create_resized** for sending structures using C language.

Is this the same way for sending Classes in C++?

Comment: You may have noticed that MPI 3 removed the C++ bindings, leaving users such as yourself a choice between the older versions of MPI (still widely found in the wild) or writing code to transform (and untransform) C++ classes (and a lot more besides) into C structures for passing between processes.  I believe that part of the reason for dropping the C++ bindings was the difficulty on agreeing a one-size-fits-all approach to destructuring C++ classes (or instances thereof) for passing.  You may want to have a look at how the BoostMPI library works

Comment: So is possible to send the Class car in a way like MPI_Send(car, ............);  using the command **MPI_Type_create_struct** ? or I should change to C and structures? What would you suggest? @HighPerformanceMark

Comment: With plain old data, there should be no issue at all, it is the same as C structures, the difference between the class and struct keyword is very subtle. The issues arise when it comes to pointers.

Comment: I already suggested you look at Boost MPI.  Did you ?

Comment: Yes, I'm still reading from here: https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_65_1/doc/html/mpi/tutorial.html#mpi.c_mapping . I didn't know about this library, thank you for the info!! If you have any other link that think is better I would like to see from there as well!